# HTML page missing 4096 characters at clientside

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iis

In my IIS webserver logfiles every now and then I find a entry with status 404 (not found) I cannot explain:

```
2011-07-06 17:05:48 W3SVC1804222802 10.248.3.8
GET /appl/localscripts/ifacobjcatFrame - 80 - 123.123.123.123
HTTP/1.0 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+
.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+
CLR+3.5.21022;+MS-RTC+EA+2;+MS-RTC+LM+8) www.example.com 404 0 2 5836 15
```

The weird part is the `GET /appl/localscripts/ifacobjcatFrame` which should indeed read:
 `GET /appl/localscripts/iface.js` because my code has:

```
[snip 1100 chars]
<script type="text/javascript" src="../localscripts/iface.js"></script>
[snip almost 4096 chars]
<div id="frm_roomFrame">
[snip another 300 char]
```

The `iface.js` gets cut off and `objcatFrame` gets appended which comes a lot further in my HTML.

I counted and it seems that exactly 4096 characters get dropped.

The weird part is that this page work fine for 999 out of 1000 of my customers with all kinds of browser version. There is just one customer that has problems.

What can an Internet Explorer make drop 4096 seemingly at random in a HTML?

Note: the logfile line shows 5836 bytes towards the end so my server claims to be sending the correct number of bytes for the page.

Comment: Only internet explorer is doing this, correct?

Comment: Please post the entire file, the page that references it, as well as a packet capture.  I suspect that you have some funky data, or some broken HTML.

Comment: As Kyle asked: Have you done tests with other browsers?+

Comment: Any browser I try myself (IE 6/7/8/9, FF, Safari) works fine. It also works fine for 999 out of 1000 other customers.  I cannot post the file here but the w3-validator finds nothing weirder than missing alt-tags for images. A packet trace is un-doable as it happens only a few times a day at random.

Comment: I might add that the customer in question has complained in the past about very slow Internet speeds. Of all our users they are furthest away physically from our server (about 500 km). Could an entire packet (4096 bytes?) be dropped in communication? Never heard of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extravagantly late answer to this question, but worth putting some notes in here so people who encounter this issue and find this page (like me) have another lead.

It looks as though this issue was a fairly obscure IE bug to do with the lookahead downloader that attempted to optimise downloading javascript (and possibly css, etc.) There's a good description [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/bugs-in-the-ie8-lookahead-downloader.aspx), and documentation for the fix [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/01/ie8-lookahead-downloader-fixed.aspx).

It basically comes down to the parser attempting to determine the charset from the first few kbs, and there being a link eligible for lookahead download spanning a kb border. The parser restarts and provides the lookahead downloader with incorrect data for its link, leading to this malformed query you see. According to that second link, the exact boundaries the link can span to cause failure, and the amount of apparently 'skipped' in the bad link can vary, but tend to be multiples of 4k.

Fortunately because the parser restarts it will still attempt to refetch the link correctly, so the user *shouldn't* see anything wrong, although of course you may have some security logic in place for users with too many bad requests, so there could be some side affects.

Hopefully this helps another reader out, because this bug had me pulling my hair out!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the symptoms in the blog you reference describe exactly the problems I am encountering. Only difference: according to the blog this is only a problem with IE8 and not IE7. Also the workaround (add content-type header) was already in place. But still, close enough to accept as an answer.

Comment: yeah our logs showed user agents from ie 7-9, although it was most prevalent in 8. I guess that it's possible there's another bug in the same sort of mechanism as described in this blog (well it seems almost certain from the evidence). i figure the 'fix' is not to aline links on kbyte boundaries but that's some pretty ghetto 1980s style coding so not really ideal. if you ever find/found a fix for this you should let me know! cheers